# Is it possible to download streamming videos off Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I like to download online streaming videos off Chromium.
Firefox can do this, but Chromium can't. Any help?

Comment: What kind of streaming video? Is it just a `<video>` tag or link to a video file, or is it something like YouTube?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to close this one and update the one [Danatela](http://askubuntu.com/users/171636/danatela) linked to as a possible dup. That way the relevant information will be consolidated rather than scattered.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. He is not asking to how to download youtube videos. He is asking how to download videos he can watch in the Chromium. Flashgot is not available for Chromium.